# Scala Set with a Tuple of 3 Elements

Tags: scala

How can I put in a tuple containing 3 elements to a Set?

Say, I have a Set of type:

```
Set[(String, String, String)]
```

How can I simply add 3 String's to my Set definition?

The following has the compiler complaining?

```
set + ("a", "b", "c")
```

Why is the tuple treated differently? It is just like any other type, so why it fails in my case above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't parse well:

```
scala> Set[(String,String,String)]() + (("a", "b", "c"))
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, String, String)] = Set((a,b,c))
```

What you wrote is parsed as Set.+(String x, String y, String z)

i.e., a function + with 3 string arguments, where what you wanted was a function + with a single 3-tuple as argument.

Comment: Set[(String,String)]() + ("a" -> "b") also works if I have just two elements. What would that mean? I mean the -> operator... What is that?

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Predef$ the Predef object holds all preimoported functions. Among those is "any2ArrowAssoc". ArrowAssoc holds the -> function. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.Predef$$ArrowAssoc.

The arrow is an infix operator to create a 2tuple from the lefthand and righthand arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Note the signature of + for HashSet as an example:

```
def +(elem1: A, elem2: A, elems: A*): HashSet[A]
```

(from http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/#scala.collection.immutable.HashSet)

This syntax implies that to add a tuple to a set of tuples would require double parentheses, one to accomodate the syntax of + and the other for the tuple. For example:

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable.HashSet
import scala.collection.immutable.HashSet

scala> val set: Set[(String, String, String)] = new HashSet[(String, String, String)]()
set: Set[(String, String, String)] = Set()

scala> val newset = set + (("one", "two", "three"))
newset: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, String, String)] = Set((one,two,three))
```

This issue does not occur for sets of elements that are not bounded by parentheses since then there is no confusion with the syntax of +.